# Tomcat 7.0.52 JNDI error while deploying a WAR file

Tags: java, apache, sql-server-2008, tomcat, jndi

The DB is : MSSQL 2008 R2
OS= Windows Server 2008 R2

Global Resource in server.xml is:

```
<Resource name="data source name" auth="Container"  type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="myuser" password="abc@xyz"  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=test1;selectMethod=cursor"  maxWait="30000" maxActive="32" maxIdle="4" initialSize="4"  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="600000" minEvictableIdleTimeMilllis="600000" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

Are the resource values conflicting or is there any other issue ? I have also tried adding tomcat user file in Resource name tag but won't work either.
I have also defined data source name in context.xml file.

The error log is:

Mar 12, 2014 5:19:53 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [UserDatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [UserDatabase].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Mar 12, 2014 5:19:53 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Failed to start "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm/1.0" realm
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[UserDatabaseRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 17 more

Comment: I feel there is a problem with your resource name it should be only one word

Comment: It is actually one word I intentionally replaced it when posting the question.

Comment: Could you share your context.xml? And, if you want to use MSSQL to authenticate users, use [DataSource Database Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html#DataSource_Database_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm).

Comment: Thanks. I have added a <ResourceLink global="data source name" name="data source name" /> in addition. No other entries.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken your `server.xml`. If you have a `<Realm>` pointing to "UserDatabase", then you need to have a `<Resource>` called "UserDatabase". Here is the default configuration:

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

If you want to use your relational database for your `<Realm>`, then you need to change the configuration to point to that instead, and you need to use a `DataSourceRealm` instead.

Comment: Do you mean <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="data source name" /> should work ?